# ¿Es compatible pip con Package Manager en Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip, instalacion, linux-mint

Linux (Mint Ulyana) trae Python 2.7 y Python 3.8 instalados por default, pero no `pip`.

El método normal para instalar módulos Python es vía Package Manager. Por supuesto, no todos los módulos están disponibles o en sus últimas versiones por esta vía.

El utilitario `pip` está disponible vía Package Manager, pero ¿puedo usarlo para instalar módulos y/o versiones que no están disponibles en Package Manager sin provocar conflictos o generar inconsistencias?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no tiene que ver con programación, si no con el funcionamiento de software.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría usar un entorno virtual (`python3 -m venv ~/carpeta`), activarlo (`source ~/carpeta/bin/activate`) y luego ya usar `pip` que te instalará lo que sea en ese entorno virtual, sin conflictos con el python de sistema. Antes de eso posiblemente tengas que instalar via package manager tanto `pip` como `python3-venv` (o como se llame)

Comment: @Gabitohh Hasta que no abran un sitio como Server Fault o Super User en español, creo que esta pregunta viene mucho al caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar ambas herramientas para instalar un mismo paquete puede crear inconsistencias.

Lo más recomendable es usar solamente uno para instalar determinado paquete.

Por poner un ejemplo, digamos que por error yo fuera a instalar `awscli` con ambas herramientas en mi máquina con Ubuntu 20.04.

```sh
baruch@hal-9000:~$ pip3 install awscli
```

Luego, para comprobar en dónde está el ejecutable que se manda a llamar con el comando `aws`, probamos lo siguiente:

```sh
baruch@hal-9000:~$ whereis aws
aws: /home/baruch/.local/bin/aws /home/baruch/.local/bin/aws.cmd
```

Ahora instalemos el mismo paquete pero con apt:

```sh
baruch@hal-9000:~$ sudo apt install awscli
```

Con lo cual, ahora tendremos un ejecutable adicional:

```sh
baruch@hal-9000:~$ whereis aws
aws: /usr/bin/aws /home/baruch/.local/bin/aws /home/baruch/.local/bin/aws.cmd
```

Aquí es donde se complican las cosas, al ver el orden de los ejecutables, uno podría pensar que se va a ejecutar siempre `/usr/bin/aws` por estar al principio, sin embargo, esto es lo que sucede:

```sh
baruch@hal-9000:~$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.159 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.0-51-generic botocore/1.18.18
baruch@hal-9000:~$ sudo aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.69 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.0-51-generic botocore/1.16.19
```

**Versiones diferentes**.

Distintos usuarios pueden estar usando diferentes versiones de un mismo programa, esto se complica si usan una misma fuente de datos.

Tengo la impresión (no comprobada) de que el usuario www-data, de uso común en servidores web podría sufrir de este mismo problema.

Comment: Experimente esos mismos síntomas. Pase dos días tratando de arreglar el entuerto, y sólo consegui empeorar la situación. Termine reinstalando Linux.

Comment: Me ha pasado jaja